# WPF Get UserControl owner (the container element)

Tags: wpf, user-controls

so I have this UserControl that's inside of another UserControl. Lets call them ParentUC and ChildUC. I need to get ParentUC from ChildUC.

I know to get the window owner would be `Window.GetWindow(userControl)`, but UserControl doesn't have a method like this AFAIK.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I came up with this solution, but post if you have a better one. Thanks!

```
DependencyObject ucParent = this.Parent;

while (!(ucParent is UserControl))
{
    ucParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(ucParent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child)` to return the parent in the Visual Tree (the parent user control from a nested user control).

Comment: I did that but it gets the grid that contains the control, that's the reason I had to loop until it gets the first UserControl in the logical tree. And I think it's better to use the LogicalTreeHelper so the loop doesn't get into the templates, adorners, etc. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

UserControl has a .Parent property that should give you access to it's parent.

Then you can cast it to your ParentUC object.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the UserControl might be inside of a StackPanel, that is inside of a Grid, that is inside of the parent UserControl, in which case myUserControl.Parent will be a StackPanel, myUserControl.Parent.Parent would be a Grid, and finally myUserControl.Parent.Parent.Parent (lol of course this is simplified by not casting the parent to StackPanel or Grid) would be the UserControl. That's why I use the loop to get the first UserControl found on top of the child one.

Comment: Haha, I saw the solution you had posted (not realizing that you had asked the question as well) and since the question appeared (to me) to indicate that the ChildUC was a direct child of ParentUC, I wanted to provide a more simple answer. Given the additional information to your scenario, I think the solution you came up with is what you need to do.

Comment: Yeah seems so. Somewhere I read that's what Window.GetWindow(UIElement) does, so I guess that's the best bet. Thanks for the suggestion though!